# how to Get the Folder and Files and Inner Folders or Files in MicrosoftGraph Query

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

In MicrosoftGraph i want to know how to make a query which is gives to me Perticular Folder and inner Folder items or files.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='jpg')? Select=name,id,webUrl,*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [try](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) this query and see if you get the desired results.

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Your Folder
>   Path/?$expand=children($select=id,name)

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/DocImgs/?$expand=children($select=id,name)

Comment: Did you get the desired results?

Comment: Yes Sir, this gives my Folder Data Files and i want to know if this folder have some inner folder and i want to know get the data from all inner folders i mean nested folder data. or files..

Comment: i mean my main folder is docimgs its have 3 inner folders like test1 test2 test3 and all three folder have some images files. and i want to get all files and folder informations

Comment: I think currently there's no way to query the drive items recursively for child items. Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Hi @hemantrajoria if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.